# MySQL query slows way down when inserting into file

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

This is my first question since every question I have ever had has already had an answer on here. please forgive the poor formatting.

The query runs in 1ms by itself which is great. It produces about 600,000 results from about 3 million entries while the database is getting inserted into about 10 per second. I know this is not very much for a database so I assume load is not an issue. I have other large queries that insert just fine into a file. This one specifically, when "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE" is added, runs in about 11 hours. This is way too long for the query to run and I have no idea why.

Table: container_table

-`Primary Key: containerID(bigint), mapID(int), cavityID(int)`

-`Index: timestamp(datetime)`

Table: cont_meas_table

-`Primary Key: containerID(bigint), box(int), probe(int), inspectionID(int), measurementID(int)`

Table: cavity_map

-`Primary Key: mapID(int), gob(char), section(int), cavity(int)`

Query:

```
(SELECT  'containerID','timestamp','mapID','lineID','fp','fpSequence','pocket','cavityID', 'location','inspResult',
     'otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1','otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1','RatioPrb2_1','otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1',
     'otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2','otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2','RatioPrb2_2','otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2',
     'otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3','otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3','RatioPrb2_3')
UNION
(SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'testcsv.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 FROM
(SELECT          containerID, timestamp, groupmeas.mapID, lineID, fp, fpSequence, pocket,     cavityID, CONCAT(MIN(section), MIN(gob)) AS location,
             inspResult, otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1, otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1, 
             (COALESCE(otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1/NULLIF(CAST(otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1 AS DECIMAL(10,5)), 0), 0)) AS RatioPrb2_1,
             otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1, otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2, otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2,
             (COALESCE(otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2/NULLIF(CAST(otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2 AS DECIMAL(10,5)), 0), 0)) AS RatioPrb2_2,
             otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2, otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3, otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3,
             (COALESCE(otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3/NULLIF(CAST(otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3 AS DECIMAL(10,5)), 0), 0)) AS RatioPrb2_3
FROM 
(SELECT   dbad.container_table.containerID, dbad.container_table.timestamp, dbad.container_table.mapID, dbad.container_table.lineID, dbad.container_table.fp, 
      dbad.container_table.fpSequence, dbad.container_table.pocket, dbad.container_table.cavityID, dbad.container_table.inspResult, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1 IS NULL
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1 END AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1 END AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1 END AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2 END AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2 END AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2 END AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3 END AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3 END AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3, 
      CASE WHEN aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_3 IS NULL 
         THEN - 1 ELSE aggMeas.otgOORMeasValuePrb2_3 END AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_3
 FROM   dbad.container_table 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT     containerID, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 0) AND (meas.probe = 0) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 1) AND (meas.probe = 0) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 2) AND (meas.probe = 0) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_1, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 0) AND (meas.probe = 1) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 1) AND (meas.probe = 1) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 2) AND (meas.probe = 1) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_2, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 0) AND (meas.probe = 2) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 1) AND (meas.probe = 2) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3, 
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN (meas.inspectionID = 1) AND (meas.measurementID = 2) AND (meas.probe = 2) THEN meas.value END), - 1) AS otgOORMeasValuePrb2_3
       FROM  (SELECT  containerID, inspectionID, measurementID, probe, value, threshold, calibration FROM  dbad.cont_meas_table AS a) AS meas
       GROUP BY containerID) AS aggMeas 
    ON dbad.container_table.containerID = aggMeas.containerID) AS groupmeas
INNER JOIN
dbad.cavity_map
  ON groupmeas.mapID=dbad.cavity_map.mapID  AND
  groupmeas.cavityID=dbad.cavity_map.cavity
  WHERE timestamp LIKE '2014-08-29%'
    AND otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    AND otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_2 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    AND otgMinThickMeasValuePrb2_3 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    AND otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    AND otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_2 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    AND otgMaxThickMeasValuePrb2_3 BETWEEN 1 AND 499
GROUP BY containerID) AS outside)
```

I have gotten rid of any `COUNT()` or `DISTINCT` and removed the leading '%' in my `WHERE timestamp LIKE '2014-08-29%'` so that timestamp's index can be used. Unfortunately, this hasn't helped.

EDIT:
After adding

`WHERE timestamp >= '2014-08-29'
   AND timestamp <  '2014-08-29' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

The query actually takes longer. I know this shouldn't be the case so I must be doing something terribly wrong in this query.

Comment: you're selecting from derived tables/subqueries about 4 levels deep, of course performance is going to be crap.

Comment: Gosh, this is a complex query. To performance troubleshoot it, you may want to break it down into pieces.

Comment: I assume the file that is being written to is on the same drive/location as the database engine?  (it's not a different physical machine than the one hosting the database right?)  And don't forget about the happy little trees.

Comment: discard the file i/o problem by first addressing the query performance by itself.

Comment: Can you test in parts to see where it's slowing? Do you have permissions to run an execution plan?

Comment: @sebas didn't he state the query itself runs in 1 ms?  I guess I assumed the 600,000 was generated in 1 ms...

Comment: @xQbert Right, I understood he was talking about another query, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure your database is properly configured to process this kind of workload, run the open source tool mysqltuner and look at the suggestions.

Your problem description sounds like you possibly want different tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size in my.cnf

You can find the tool here: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

Comment: I have heard of this but company policy keeps me from using it.

Comment: "Company policy keeps me from using it." -- good.  Tuning scripts are a terrible idea.  Just concentrate on the query.

Comment: There has been good advice offered in some of the comments.  Your query, without `INTO OUTFILE` may be slower than you think, due to the query cache, which wouldn't be accessible to `INTO OUTFILE`.  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` (without the outfile) will confirm that.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will show you the query plan and is extremely valuable for performance troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

One thing jumps up and smacks me in the face here:

```
WHERE timestamp LIKE '2014-08-29%'  /* slow! */
```

This defeats the use of the index on the `timestamp` column, because it implicitly casts `timestamp` to a string.

Try using this instead:

```
WHERE timestamp >= '2014-08-29'
  AND timestamp <  '2014-08-29' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That will allow the query to use an index range scan on the `timestamp` which may help a lot. It works because it casts the constant dates to the same datatype as `timestamp` instead of the other way around.

The point of an index is to avoid what's called a full table scan, in which the MySQL server has to romp through every row of your table looking for matching data. Omitting a `WHERE` clause also makes the server look at every row of a table.

Comment: I upvoted but when the database was brand new (<200,000 entries) I ran this query with no `WHERE timestamp` statement and it ran for 6 hours. I really appreciate this though and will change my query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need and can optimize your query: replace

```
LIKE '% 29-08-2014'
```

for

```
>= "08-29-2014" and <'2014-08-30'
```

In some cases It is faster to process data from a temporary table by using JOIN instead of multiple subqueries, then you can try creating temporary tables